# Double arrow in GraphPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphs-and-networks

Is it possible to combine two edges into one with a double arrow?

For example:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

results something like

[image]

Is it possible to change it to something like

[image]

without using the drawing tool to edit the graphics directly?

Comment: Which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: version 8 on Mac.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a hack, but it'll work with `GraphPlot`:

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2}, MultiedgeStyle -> .001, 
 DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that works. But the combined line seems slightly thicker than the others, do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: @user0501 Unfortunately no.  I'd have to search the docs more for that and right now I do not have the time.  Also, ideally there should be a solution for `Graph` objects, not just `GraphPlot`.  My answer is by no means complete.

Comment: @user0501 I'm trying to do the same thing with `LayeredGraphPlot` with little success, so I might try Szabolcs solution. However, from your comment, to deal with the thicker double arrow, could you add something in such that if a rule and its inverse are both found, to reduce the thickness of each resulting edge by 50%?

Answer (score 2):

The option settings `False` and `None` are not listed among documented *typical settings*, but  both  `MultiedgeStyle -> False` and `MultiedgeStyle -> None` give the desired result.

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1}, 
 MultiedgeStyle -> False,  
 DirectedEdges -> True, VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2}, 
  MultiedgeStyle -> False, 
  DirectedEdges -> True,  VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

```
GraphPlot[{1 -> 2, 2 -> 1, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 2}, 
  MultiedgeStyle -> None, 
  DirectedEdges -> True,  VertexLabeling -> True]
```

[image]

**Notes:**

- This works in version 9 (windows 10) and in version 11.2 on Wolfram Cloud.
- After major updates in version 12.0, `GraphPlot` usage/options changed completely. Use `` GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy `` instead of `GraphPlot` for the code above to work.